# Get an AttributeError in Python Tkinter. How to fix it?

Tags: python, tkinter

This is just a simple practice of Python Tkinter. 
Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()
    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title('GUI')
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        text = Entry(self, bd=1)
        text.pack(side = TOP)

        submit_b = Button(self, text = 'submit', command = self.submit)
        submit_b.pack(side = BOTTOM)
    def submit(self):
        print(self.text.get())

root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x50')

app = Window(root)

root.mainloop()
```

The result is like this:

[image]

So I enter a string in the 'Entry' and click 'submit' button. This program will print out the string.

However, I got this:

```
AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I have no idea why it didn't work. Please help me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just forgot the [`self`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2709821/1639625) in the declaration of `text`:

```
    self.text = Entry(self, bd=1)
    self.text.pack(side = TOP)
```

Thus `text` was a local variable and promptly "forgotten" after `__init__` finished. This way, it is a member variable of the instance and can be accessed from within `submit`. Note that, other than e.g. with Java's `this`, Python does not automatically look for an instance variable if no local variable of the same name has been found. `self` is *not* optional or just for disambiguation.

Alternatively, you could keep `text` as a local variable, but make `submit` local, too:

```
    text = Entry(self, bd=1)
    text.pack(side = TOP)
    def submit():
        print(text.get())
    submit_b = Button(self, text = 'submit', command = submit)
    submit_b.pack(side = BOTTOM)
```

For `submit_b`, you do not need `self`, as you do not refer to that button outside of the `__init__` method. In fact, after the call to `pack`, you do not refer to the button at all, so you could even do:

```
    Button(self, text = 'submit', command = submit).pack(side = BOTTOM)
```

Comment: It is correct! Thank you! But can I ask you why submit_b need not to add self.?